# Impossible VM-detection countermeasures

Tags: virtualization, antimalware, detection

Are there any vm-detection techniques (of malware) which are impossible to mitigate in your vm?

If yes, which?

Comment: Interesting question, but very broad. And the answers would change over time. Maybe it should focus on specifc VM software. That said, I'm thinking you could look at the clock. And interaction with the outside world. But no concrete idea, certainly nothing that can't be dodged by a wary VM builder.

Comment: This post will probably be closed because the question is way to broad to be specifically answered. I believe a simple google search would suffice: https://www.google.com/search?ei=JMRoWtiTM8ixzwK5n4LoBA&q=vm+detection+techniques&oq=vm-detection+techniques

Comment: @WatchDog but which of those cannot be mitigated? That's the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the system firmware tables is a good way to tell, since the VM will not use a normal BIOS. On Windows you can use [EnumSystemFirmwareTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724259(v=vs.85).aspx) to read them. You can build a VM that attempts to hide this, but it's an annoying process to set up and in general very hard to fake a real system's firmware tables convincingly, since one of the tables is the BIOS/UEFI firmware blob.

MSRs and PCH scratch register contents are also pretty hard to fake, but that requires a lot of platform-specific knowledge and effort to implement checks for.

[Al-Khaser](https://github.com/LordNoteworthy/al-khaser) is a test framework which includes many VM identification tricks, and is a good reference for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux systems you can check the value of /proc/cpuinfo and search for the word "hypervisor" on the flag section. Check this two examples

```
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single intel_pt kaiser tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
```

And in a VM using vmware

```
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat xsaveopt pln pts dts
```

Comment: Clearly I can build a custom kernel that hides these flags, so I'm not sure how those fit in "impossible to mitigate"